# Display div container with a fixed position in a iframe

Tags: html, iframe, css-position

I have HTML content which displays a div box always on top:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .fixedtop1 { position: fixed; top: 5px; left: 0; right: 15px; border: 1px solid black; z-index: 50; padding: 5px}
    .center250a { width: 350px; margin-left: auto; background-color: #f0f0f0; } 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="height:1000px">
    <div style="margin-top:20px" class="fixedtop1 center250a">  
        <div class="text-style" style="float:left;margin-right:2px"><b>Test:</b></div><div>0</div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
 <p> Just a Test </p>
<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is now that `position: fixed` uses the **viewport** as the container element but the HTML content above should be integrated within a iframe. So the example works without using a iframe as a standalone HTML page but not with a iframe.

How to solve? It is not possible for me to but some div-elements of the HTML content above outside the iframe but I can give the iframe tag some style properties.

Answer (score 0):

iframe and it's parent are different documents with different browse context.
So elements inside of iframe don't interact with the iframe parent and can't be fixed relative to it.

Instead of setting fixed position in div-element you need to set it in the iframe.

The elements inside the iframe won't need to be positioned fixed.

Comment: Maybe you missunderstood me...I do not want to fix the position of the iframe but the div container IN the iframe. Please provide an example.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand your question. Do you want that your div container (inside an iframe) stays fixed at the top of the page, right?

Comment: Not at the top of the page but at the top of the iframe, yes.